# Toast doesn't appear

Tags: android, toast

So, I have `import android.widget.toast`, and I receive no errors when compiling. However, the following:

```
private void checkAnswer(boolean userPressedTrue){
    boolean isAnswerTrue = mQuestionBank[mCurrentIndex].isTrueQuestion();

    int messageResId = 0;

    if (userPressedTrue == isAnswerTrue){
        messageResId = R.string.correct_toast;
    } else {
        messageResId = R.string.incorrect_toast;
    }

    Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);

}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz);

    mQuestionTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.question_text_view);

    mTrueButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.true_button);
    mTrueButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkAnswer(true);
        }
    });
    mFalseButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.false_button);
    mFalseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            checkAnswer(false);
        }
    });
```

does not display on my phone. I made sure that notification weren't disabled for the app.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to call show() method after makeText();

```
    Toast.makeText(this.getApplicationContext(), messageResId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```